# kineticjs add shadow to group or layer

Tags: kineticjs

How do I add a shadow to a group of objects or layer groups, it may be possible to add any function to class layer

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be difficult since shadowing is linked to the Shape object. Of course, you can set shadow to all your layer elements... Or then, the better I can do is taking the layer, doing an image with it, and then shadowing this image.

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 400,
      height: 200
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 20,
      y: 20,
      width: 100,
      height: 50,
      fill: "green",
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 2
  });
  var rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
      x: 20,
      y: 20,
      width: 50,
      height: 100,
      fill: "blue",
      stroke: 'black',
      strokeWidth: 2
  });

  layer.add(rect1);
  layer.add(rect2);
  stage.add(layer);

  var layerImage = new Image();
  layerImage.src = layer.getCanvas().toDataURL();

  layerImage.onload = function () {
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      var shadowedImage = new Kinetic.Image({
          image: layerImage,
          shadowColor: 'black',
          shadowBlur: 2,
          shadowOffset: {
              x: 10,
              y: 10
          },
          shadowOpacity: 0.5
      });
      layer.add(shadowedImage);
      stage.add(layer);
  }
```